# DirectX/XAML interop input latency

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, directx

My app is using XAML/DirectX interop on Windows Phone 8 using DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid. I'm experiencing significant input latency on touch in my C++ component. Time from actual touch to PointerPressed event firing is in an order of hundreds of milliseconds, which is not ok. Has anyone had same issue, or know what can I do to make this faster? I've been googling for some time and have found nothing, so any answer is greatly appreciated.